# mysql performance issue with consistently read/write on table

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a page which is accessed like 500K times a day and each time a user views this page,

1) I write into name-A table, which is cleaned daily to maintain maximum 700 records;

2) I pull to list the last 50 records;

This is extremely slow. I have to optimize the table or change the logic. My question is

1) what kind of optimization can be done to the table?

2) if not much can be done, then I have to change the design, right?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your request (point 2) please?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use indexes on primary key and any other field you frequently retrieve results by.

2) It's probably better to use InnoDB on the table you write to frequently as it supports row level locking (as opposed to table level locking provided by MyISAM).

3) In your application logic, start caching results of queries if possible. It will significantly reduce the stress on your database.

Comment: thanks. if I turn off the write part, how much will it improve?

Comment: It depends. Another good thing about InnoDB is it supports transactions. That way you can do all your writes in a batch and improve performance a little, with the added benefit of rollback capabilities.